# как в pyrogram вводить номер телефона из кода в командную строку

Tags: pyrogram

при входе в аккаунт в командной строке нужно ввести номер телефона как реализовать это через код без app.connect так как он просит пароль[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, это ли ты имеешь в виду, так как непонятно задал вопрос, но номер телефона можно передавать как аргумент при создании объекта класса.

```
app = Client("my_account", phone_number="+12312312312")
```